# Using -n option with pushd and popd

Tags: bash

1. `popd`

   > Remove the top entry from the directory stack, and cd to the new top directory. When no arguments are given, popd removes the top directory from the stack and performs a cd to the new top directory. The elements are numbered from 0 starting at the first directory listed with dirs; that is, popd is equivalent to popd +0.
   >
   > -n
   >   Suppresses the normal change of directory when removing directories from the stack, so that only the stack is manipulated.

   ```
   /home/t$ dirs -v
    0  ~
    1  /tmp
    2  ~/mydata
   /home/t$ popd -n
   ~ ~/mydata
   /home/t$ dirs -v
    0  ~
    1  ~/mydata
   ```

   Why not:

   ```
   /home/t$ dirs -v
    0  /tmp
    1  ~/mydata
   ```
2. `pushd`

   > Options:
   >
   > ```
   >  -n     Suppresses the normal change of directory when adding
   >         directories to the stack, so only the stack is manipulated.
   > ```
   >
   > Arguments:
   >
   > ```
   >  +N     Rotates the stack so that the Nth directory (counting
   >         from the left of the list shown by `dirs', starting with
   >         zero) is at the top.
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   >  -N     Rotates the stack so that the Nth directory (counting
   >         from the right of the list shown by `dirs', starting with
   >         zero) is at the top.
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   >  dir    Adds DIR to the directory stack at the top, making it the
   >         new current working directory.
   > ```

   ```
   /tmp$ dirs -v
    0  /tmp
    1  ~
    2  ~/mydata
   /tmp$ pushd -n +1
   /tmp$ dirs -v
    0  /tmp
    1  ~/mydata
    2  /tmp
   ```

   why not:

   ```
   /tmp$ dirs -v
    0  ~
    1  ~/mydata
    2  /tmp
   ```

   or

   `/tmp$ dirs -v
    0  /tmp
    1  ~
    2  ~/mydata`

Answer (score 3):

The top of your `dirs` stack is always your current directory. And `-n` should prevent the change of the directory. So `-n` should prevent the change of the top of the stack.

Suppose you are in `~` (then the top of your stack is `~`). Now you run `popd` **without** `-n`. The very top element `~`of the stack is then removed and your current directory changes to `/tmp`.

```
~ $

 0  ~
 1  /tmp
 2  ~/mydata 

~ $ popd

 0  /tmp
 1  ~/mydata

/tmp $ # you are now in /tmp
```

The flag `-n` should suppress this behavior. So instead of removing the very top element of the stack it removes that one which is second to the top. Thus, if you run `popd -n` your current directory stays the same.

```
~ $

 0  ~
 1  /tmp  # we will remove this one
 2  ~/mydata 

~ $ popd -n

 0  ~
 1  ~/mydata

~ $ # you are still in ~
```

---

For `pushd`, it is more complicated. The `+N` notation moves the Nth element to the top, rotating the stack. So if you  are in `/tmp` (your top of the stack is then `/tmp`) and run `pushd +1` you have the following transformation of the stack and your current directory is changed to `~`:

```
/tmp $ pushd +1

             ----------------------------
             |                          |
 0  /tmp -----     |------>0 ~          |
 1  ~ --------------   |-->1 /mydata    |
 2  ~/mydata------------   2 /tmp  <----|


~ $ # you are now in ~
```

Again `-n` should suppress the change of your current directory. So it does all the same but instead of putting `~` to the top of the stack, it just leaves the top of the stack unchanged (i.e., `/tmp`):

```
/tmp $ pushd -n +1

             ----------------------------
             |                          |
 0  /tmp -----     |------>0 /tmp       | # instead of ~ 
 1  ~ --------------   |-->1 /mydata    |
 2  ~/mydata------------   2 /tmp  <----|


/tmp $ # you are still in /tmp
```

Well, I agree that this is not an obvious behavior. But it becomes more understandable if you remember that putting a directory to the top happens by making `cd` into this directory. In the last example (`pushd -n +1`), the command `cd ~` is not executed because `-n` flag is specified. Thus, you are still in `/tmp` and so the top of the stack is still `/tmp`.

Answer (score -2):

It is pretty obvious what `-n` does: It doesn't change the stack at index 0.

Index 0 is always the `$PWD` (or `pwd`) and is **not** changed if option `-n` is used.

That is: `popd` or `pushd` will not execute a `cd`.

For other issues raise a new question.